# Centering a div that contains images whose size is relative to the page width

Tags: html, css, centering

I've tried the solutions in other threads, but I'm at a loss.
I'd like two images, side by side, each one's width equal to 40% of the page width, and with 20px of margin between them, and the whole wazoo should be centered.
Diagrammed approximately:

```
|            [img1 width:40%] 20px space [img2 width:40%]            |
```

I've gotten very close, but nothing quite works.
Here's the closest I've gotten:

```
<!-- Starts centering with the addition of "width" to the div's style. -->
<div style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <img width=40% src="http://bit.ly/1mlbOp6" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img width=40% src="http://bit.ly/1mlbOp6" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 20px;">
</div>
```

This code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98Se3/

It resolutely refuses to center without that div having a specified width. However, the width of the div can neither be set relative to the page width, or exactly in pixels, because it should be 40% + 20px + 40%.
What am I missing?

Comment: It's not related to your question but you should write <img width="40%" .. with quotation marks

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Style is important to readability. This is my first ever SO question: There are a bunch of equivalent, equally right answers. Can I acknowledge more than one?

Comment: and width / height in html are without unit like px or % : (img width="20") You can use % or px in CSS.

Comment: You can upvote for all the answers which works and choose the one which is well explained with a demo. As you want !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use text-align:center for the parent div:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <img width="40%" src="http://bit.ly/1mlbOp6">
    <img width="40%" src="http://bit.ly/1mlbOp6" style="margin-left: 20px;">
</div>
```

Check out this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98Se3/5/)

Comment: I see! This works perfectly for me, thanks. Am I correct in understanding that this works because setting the images to display as inline-block makes them act fundamentally like text, so text-align applies to them?

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to make them inline-block, check my updated fiddle. And `text-align:center` will center anything, including block-level elements

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbbottam/98Se3/1/)

```
<!-- Starts working (approximately) with the addition of "width" to the div's style. -->
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%">
    <img width=40% src="http://bit.ly/1mlbOp6" style="display: inline-block;"><img width=40% src="http://bit.ly/1mlbOp6" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 20%;">
</div>
```

Updated `margin-left: 20%;` instead of `margin-left: 20px;`

And there is no gap between `<img ...><img ..>`

Answer (score 1):

`<div style="text-align:center">...</div>`

This way the content is centered, the div uses full width but unless it needs to be visible (border, background-color, ...) it does not visually matter.
That last part may be solved by setting a `<span>` around the images and style that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `text-align:center;` instead `margin:0 auto;`

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/98Se3/3/)